# Go and Grapqhl setup not working on mac in documents folder

Tags: go, graphql, gqlgen

I was following this tutorial https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-go/1-getting-started/ and had a hard time getting it to work.

First, i tried all this in a subfolder of my `Documents` folder. However, after step
`go run github.com/99designs/gqlgen init` only the schema was created.

However, if i execute the same steps in, e.g. a subfolder of `Deskotp`, everything gets created correctly.

Should be structure:

```
.
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── gqlgen.yml
├── graph
│   ├── generated
│   │   └── generated.go
│   ├── model
│   │   └── models_gen.go
│   ├── resolver.go
│   ├── schema.graphqls
│   └── schema.resolvers.go
└── server.go

3 directories, 9 files
```

Structure if executed in sub folder of `Documents`:

```
.
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
└── graph
    └── schema.graphqls

1 directory, 3 files
```

Operating system: macOS Big Sur, 11.6 (MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019))
Go version: go version go1.17.4 darwin/amd64

Can anyone help me out on why this does not work in the `Documents` sub tree?

Thanks a lot.

edit: As suggested `go env`

```
GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/Users/ferdinand/Library/Caches/go-build"
GOENV="/Users/ferdinand/Library/Application Support/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOEXPERIMENT=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/Users/ferdinand/go/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/ferdinand/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GOVCS=""
GOVERSION="go1.17.4"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="clang"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/Users/ferdinand/Documents/ownSoftwareProjects/gqlgen-tools/go.mod"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -arch x86_64 -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/11/hy4ct0x12hq7yxppy9cbq7pm0000gn/T/go-build4186097959=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
```